# Query (updateOne) is creating data multiplied in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**Hello devs**. Without further ado...

I have a problem updating a column in the database. When performing an update on a column it is multiplying the data. It doesn't make any sense since the multiplied data contains the same `_id`. And that `_id` is a unique value.

Here is a part of the code that contains the query:

```
const addressId = await new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {

         await Cadastros.updateOne({_id: user_id}, {$push: {enderecos: endereco}}, (err, raw) => {
            if(err){
                if(!err._id) return reject(false);
                if(err._id) return resolve(err._id);
            }
            return resolve(false);
        });
})
```

This algorithm is responsible for adding a new address to the user's registration in the database using the `$push` method.

Follows the Schema JSON:

```
   {
        cpf: { 
          type: String,
          required: true,
          unique: true
        },
        email: { 
          type: String, 
          unique: true,
          required: true,
          max: 100,
          lowercase: true
        },
        senha: {
          type: String,
          max: 100
        },
        nome_completo: { 
          type: String, 
          max: 100 
        },
        data_de_nascimento: { 
          type: Date 
        },
        sexo: { 
          type: String,
          default: null
        },
        enderecos: [
          {
          nome_completo: {
            type: String
          },
          cep: { 
            type: Number
          },
          endereco: { 
            type: String, 
            max: 60 
          },
          num: { 
            type: Number
          },
          bairro: { 
            type: String, 
            max: 60 
          },
          cidade: { 
            type: String, 
            max: 30 
          },
          estado: { 
            type: String, 
            max: 2 
          },
          complemento: { 
            type: String, 
            max: 21, 
            default: "" 
          },
          referencia_end: { 
            type: String, 
            max: 60, 
            default: null 
          },
          celular: { 
            type: Number
          },
          principal:{
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
          }
        }
      ],
        ip: { 
          type: String, 
          max: 45 
        },
        user_agent: {
          type: String
        },
        fingerprint: {
          type: String
        },
        device_info: {
          type: String
        },
        exists: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false
        },
        data_criacao: {
          type: Date, 
          default: Date.now()
        }
      }
```

It is also the only middleware in the same table:

```
CadastrosSchema.post('updateOne', async function(doc, next){
  const data = this.getUpdate();
  
  if(data.$push ? data.$push.enderecos : false) return next({_id: data.$push.enderecos._id})
  
  next()
})
```

And the middleware part was a workaround, but it was the only way I found to return the `_id` generated from the added subdocument.

Here is the multiplied subdocument:

[There are two subdocuments with the same _id. It didn't make any sense to me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBG8P.jpg)

Anyone who knows what is going on and can bring a solution is grateful. There may also be other people with the same problem, so that would help not only me but other people. If there's a problem with that code, I can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$push` for `$addToSet` solved my problem.